# 'No module named 'pyfirmata'' error even though I have already installed pyfirmata using pip?

Tags: windows, arduino, pyfirmata

I started by uploading the StandardFirmata example from the Arduino IDE onto my Arduino UNO. I then successfully installed pyfirmata onto my windows pc using `pip3 install pyfirmata` to the path c:\users\ta319\anaconda3\lib\site-packages, however, when I try to run the following code in spyder:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pyfirmata
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    board = pyfirmata.Arduino('COM4 (Arduino UNO)')
    print("Communication Successfully started")
    
    while True:
        board.digital[13].write(1)
        time.sleep(1)
        board.digital[13].write(0)
        time.sleep(1)
```

I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
> "C:\Users\ta319\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py",
> line 356, in compat_exec
> exec(code, globals, locals)
>
> File "c:\users\ta319\firmata setup.py", line 3, in 
> import pyfirmata
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyfirmata'

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: your module pyfirmata is missing, pip3 install pyfirmata

Answer (score 0):

You probably installed with pip and not pip3, try
`python3 -m pip install pyfirmata` or `pip3 install pyfirmata`

Comment: Thank you for the comment, sorry I did actually use pip3 and have now amended my question. After using the `pip3 install pyfirmata` I got this in the terminal:                                        
C:\Users\ta319>pip3 install pyfirmata
Requirement already satisfied: pyfirmata in c:\users\ta319\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyserial in c:\users\ta319\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pyfirmata) (3.5)

Comment: In that case try ```from pyfirmata import <whatever you need>``` in your script instead of import pyfirmata